# Amazon Cognito region vs AWS Console region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Why does Amazon Cognito have it's own region? And does the region for Amazon Cognito need to be the same as the region I have set in AWS Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Cognito is only available in 3 regions as of right now. They are US East (N. Virginia), EU (Ireland) and Asia Pacific (Tokyo). But I had a region other than one of these in `console.aws.com`. But now that I tried to created a Cognito identity at `console.aws.amazon.com/cognito`, I had to choose one of the regions listed above it is only supported in a subset of `console.aws.com` regions.

To answer the more important part of my question, it is OK to choose a different region here while Beanstalk is setup to serve your application from a different region is Yes. That is how I have it setup right now.

Answer (score 3):

Like other AWS services, Cognito is available as a service in multiple regions. To access the service, you have to supply which region of it you want to access. Data for users in each region is only available for that region - if I were to create an identity inside an identity pool configured in us-east-1, I wouldn't be able to access it if I supplied region eu-west-1.

Specifically, for Cognito identity, it tracks each identity id vended and any public provider information possibly used by that identity to know if anything it is given is a valid identifier of the user.
For Cognito sync, it manages the sync data/metadata for each identity.

Yes, the region in which you configure your Cognito identity pool in the console needs to be the same as the one you give the client.

If you're using Cognito identity to get credentials for a resource in another region, that's totally supported. Credentials vended from one region can be used from another.

Comment: Thanks @JeffBailey. I was referring to regions in Cognito and then elsewhere in AWS, like Beanstalk. My answer reflects this.

Comment: Ah, yes, your answer is correct. I'll update my answer for future readers.